# alignas attribute ignored when address sanitizer is used -- gcc bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, alignment, address-sanitizer, compiler-bug

GCC codegen doesn't seem to align stack variables with the specified alignment value, when the address sanitizer is used.

The following code causes an assertion failure on g++ (GCC) 13.1.1 20230429, arch x86_64 GNU/Linux, when the flag `-fsanitize=address` is used. When the flag isn't specified, the assertion doesn't fail.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    alignas(64) char c;
    auto addr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&c);
    assert(addr % 64 == 0);
}
```

Using clang 15.0.7 on the same arch with the same flag does not cause this bug.

Is this a GCC bug?

Comment: Works here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4oxTebj8h

Comment: godbolt is using v13.1, I'm using v13.1.1

Comment: It may be that `64` exceeds the maximum supported alignment of the compiler or platform.  I ran into something like that as an issue when the PMMU required the table to be aligned on a 4096-byte address boundary, but the alignment specification was beyond the capability of the compiler to provide (I ended up doing it "the hard way",  by hand).  However, I hope this is a GCC bug that can be fixed.  (Not that I "hope for bugs", especially in a compiler.)

Comment: @clang-enjoyer Here's trunk 14.0.0 https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M4dPeq8b3

Comment: Are you using any other options besides `-fsanitize=address`?  Are you able to reproduce the problem with other gcc versions?

Comment: @NateEldredge Only the one flag. With GCC 12 codegen seems ok.

Comment: I encounter the same problem, but only on Ubuntu 23.04 (g++ (Ubuntu 13.1.0-2ubuntu2~23.04) 13.1.0). On compiler explorer and other linux distros the allocation is aligned.

Comment: It is related to the compiler flag `-fstack-protector-strong`, which is a default on some linux distributions, e.g. Ubuntu. See https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s9Ka3qcMz Is this then a compiler issue when using address sanitizer together with `-fstack-protector-strong`?

Comment: It is a compiler issue, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=110027